# Firebase Remote Config API from React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I'm using React and im trying to use this API https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/remote-config/rest/v1/projects/getRemoteConfig
to get my Remote Config.

using https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk for it does not meet my requirements because they have a bug with the Remote Config so i'm trying to use the API directly (from the docs above)

can anyone show me how i call this API ?

according to the Docs im suppose to call:

`GET https://firebaseremoteconfig.googleapis.com/v1/{project=projects/*}/remoteConfig`

what is {project=projects/*} ?

also how do i suppose to pass my APIKey or something? (like how to authenticate to use this API?)

using only HTTPS / HTTP calls

Thanks~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The API you're trying to call is meant for server-side access only, and not for access from within your (native or web) app. Calling it from within your app, exposes you users to abuse.

Aside from that:

- To learn about the process in a more readable way than the reference docs, I recommend reading the guide on [modifying remote config templates through the REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/automate-rc#modify_remote_config_using_the_rest_api).
- The `{project=projects/*}` in the URL indicates what project to get the Remote Config template from. So if your Firebase project ID is `myproject`, this would be `{project=projects/myproject}`.
- You'll need an OAuth access token with the correct scopes to be able to call this API. The process for that is shown in the documentation on [getting an access token to authenticate and authorize API requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/automate-rc#get_an_access_token_to_authenticate_and_authorize_api_requests).